# Establecer un título en el nuevo ViewController según el botón que se pulse

Tags: swift

¡Hola! Soy nuevo en esta comunidad y principiante en Swift. Dispongo de dos pantallas (ViewControllers). La primera con tres botones, y pulses el que pulses te dirigirán hacia la misma segunda pantalla. Mi objetivo es, que según el botón que pulses, el segundo ViewController tenga un título u otro, ya que también tengo que cambiar el fondo en función del título pero esto lo tengo resuelto.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myRedBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myGreenBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myBlueBtn: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func redBtn(_ sender: Any)
    {
 
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "VCColor", sender: self)
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func greenBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "VCColor", sender: self)
    }
    
    @IBAction func blueBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "VCColor", sender: self)
        
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destino = segue.destination as? ColorViewController
        destino?.titulo = "Prueba"
                
}
}
```

Mi problema es que no tengo muy claro cómo indicar en el action o en el override func prepare que según el botón que se pulse, el título será x. El código de mi segunda pantalla es el siguiente:

```
import UIKit

class ColorViewController: UIViewController {

    var titulo: String?

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        if let tituloFinal = titulo {
            self.title = tituloFinal
        }
        
        if self.title == "Red"{
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed
            }
        if self.title == "Green"{
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
        }
        if self.title == "Blue"{
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        }
        
    }
```

Supongo que debe ser algo bastante simple, aunque ya probé de todo sin resultados... Gracias de antemano, y no se alarmen de ver muchas novatadas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ayudarte del texto que tiene el `UIButton`, para esto tienes que cambiar el parámetro de tipo `Any` y que sea de tipo `UIButton`:

```
@IBAction func redButton(_ sender: UIButton) { }
```

Al llamar a la función *performSegue* en el valor de `sender` vas a enviar el botón.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "VCColor", sender: sender)
```

El código unido:

```
@IBAction func redButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "VCColor", sender: sender)
}
```

En la función para enviar los parámetros en el *segue* verificas que el `sender` sea de tipo `UIButton` y poder acceder al texto del mismo:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destino = segue.destination as? ColorViewController
    if let senderButton = sender as? UIButton {
        if let titleButton = senderButton.titleLabel?.text {     
            destino?.titulo = titleButton
        }
    }
}
```

En el otro ViewController validas el texto recibido:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    switch titulo {
        case "Yellow": self.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        case "Blue": self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        case "Red": self.view.backgroundColor = .red
        default: self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me ha ayudado muchísmo, además de haberlo podido comprender perféctamente. Ahora funciona como debería. ¡Mil gracias!